How to make this delete statement more efficient?
I have a couple of tables. Table_1 looks like this:
Customer | Offer
---------|------
1        | A
1        | B
1        | C
2        | A
2        | C
3        | A

Table_2 looks like this:
Customer | Category
---------|---------
1        | X
2        | X
3        | Y

I want to delete customers from table_1 like this:
DELETE 
FROM    TABLE_1
WHERE   OFFER IN
        (
        'A',
        'C'
        )
AND     CUSTOMER NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  CUSTOMER
        FROM    TABLE_2
        WHERE   CATEGORY = 'Y'
        )
;

So the desired result would be for table_1 to look like this:
Customer | Offer
---------|------
1        | B
3        | A

The query above does produce the correct result, but it takes a long time to run (table_1 is ~120m rows and table_2 is ~3m). Does anyone know if there is a more efficient way of reaching the same result please? Database is DB2 if that helps.

What indexes are present for both tables? What runstats are doing on those tables and those indexes?  Have you examined the access-plan?

I'm not so familiar with DB2, but you can try correlated sub-query like here https://sqlize.online/s/lN

With all performance questions, details matter. Like @mao said, information about indexes and statistics are important to provide any help. They determine the access plan Db2 picks / can pick.

Please include your platform and version of Db2 also..

Would a join be more performant?

Create the index: create index ix1 on table_2 (customer, category); and post the plan in Check The Plan.

First, make sure you have the following indexex :
Table_1 (offer, customer)
Table_2 (category, customer)
Once you've ensure that those indexes exist, run an EXPLAIN over your statement and post back the results.
Lastly, which version of DB2 are you running, and on which operating system?
